# Find probability of complex event.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Okay, so today I've had task in my test, which is supposed to be hard:

Cafe serves donuts. Every day number of students eat in this cafe. $\frac{3}{5}$ of these students are engineers, and $\frac{2}{5}$ are philosophers. It is known, that in average $15\%$ of engineers, and $20\%$ of philosophers buy a donut. What is the probability of a student to buy a donut?

Okay, **engineer buying a donut** and **philosopher buying a donut** are two independent events. So am I right that final answer is:

$\frac{2}{5}×20\%$ + $\frac{3}{5}×15\%$=$17\%$

Test is supposed to be hard, but this task is seems really simple, that's why I'm asking. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, that's right. Maybe other questions were hard.

Comment: Hard is in the eye of the beholder.